# Mahler's $3/2$ problem

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Mahler's $3/2$ problem described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahler%27s_3/2_problem).  Am I right in thinking the following would prove it?

Show that for every integer $m$, there is some integer $n$ for which the fractional part $$\left\{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n\right\}\gt1-\frac{1}{2^m}$$

Because for every real number $x$ which generates some fractional part there will be an $x=1/2^m$ which generates a still smaller frational part.

If so, the problem does not look so difficult on the face of it.  In fact surely the irrationality of $\log_2{(3)}$ ensures it?

If my restatement is not correct, is there an example of when and why my restatement would not correspond with the original form?

Comment: The RHS of your formula makes no sense. Do you perhaps mean $1/(1+2^{-m})$ ?

Comment: @JohnBentin D'Oh! Fixed

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen sorry for the error, I think my edit and your comment have crossed each other

Comment: Indeed. But are you really saying that if there is a Z-number $x$ then there is also a Z-number of the form $1/2^m$? Why would that be the case?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I hadn't realised that. I arrived at this problem when studying Collatz conjecture and wondered if they are equivalent.  Your statement suddenly makes that possibility look significantly more likely. Perhaps truth of the Collatz conjecture would make that the case.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen what I meant to suggest was that for every real number $x$ which generates some fractional part, we can always choose some $1/2^m$ instead of $x$ which would generate an even smaller fractional part.  Therefore we only need to prove that for every denominator of the form $2^m$, no matter how large this denominator (and therefore how small the fraction), there is always some $(3/2)^n$ large enough to overcome it when multiplied.